# Render json and nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have these classes:

```
class Product
 attr_accessible :name, ...
 has_many :images
end

class Image
 attr_accessible :image, :position, :product_id, :title
 belongs_to :product
end
```

Action:

```
def list
  render :json => {:Result => "OK", :Records => Product.all}
end
```

How can I include the own images for every product as nested attribute and not enumerate all attributes in the product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `to_json(:include => :attr)`

```
def list
  render :json => {:Result => "OK", :Records => Product.all}.to_json(:include => :images)
end
```

Comment: I don't mean to nitpick, but shouldn't the code be `Product.all(:include => :images).to_json`?

Comment: @dimitko for what I quickly tested on my machine, even if you loaded nested objects beforehand via `all(:include => ...)`, json will not include them in the output.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think that was a problem in one of the Rails versions, but might be wrong. So obviously your solution is much better, thanks, gonna do my best to remember that code piece.

Comment: @dimitko I tested on Rails2/Ruby1.8 so what you said might work in Rails3+.